# file only saves one time data when use in loop

Tags: c++, copy, file-handling

I have made a code in which data is taken from one whole file and only part of it is stored in the other file. But when I put it in loop it does not work has it should and I am having trouble locating the error can someone guide me where I am doing mistake.
Here is the things what my below written code does:
Takes user name from the user and creates the user name file then asks user if he wants to choice how many books from English book shelf he wants to choice.

NOW THE ERROR: 
it does not take multiple inputs if user press 2 it only takes 1 input and copies one book no name to user file but does not do it for the next time

I MAY HAVE SOME CLUE MAYBE: 
I think it maybe the get-line in using in the code, which may not be working for the second time the loop executes.

I have tried modifying my code in mostly each possible way I could, but I think may be I'm still new to programming field. So my logical thinking may be not so good. That is why I need little guidance only.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
string user;
int main()
{ 
  cout<<"enter your name to create your Libaray file for book record\n";
  getline(cin,user);
  ofstream outFile(user.c_str(),ios::app);  //user named file
  string line;
  ifstream inFile("English_book_shelf.txt"); //file with books name and 
                                             //number(labels)
  int count,c;
  cout<<"How many books do you want to buy?\n";
  cin>>c;
  for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
  {
    cout<<"Enter your choices:\n";
    cin>>count;
    while(count)
    { 
      getline(inFile, line);
      if (--count == 0)
      {
        outFile << line <<endl;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want my code to take multiple input from the user and store it in the user file.
Like if he want 3 books, the code should run copy 3 books from the book shelf file and copy it in the user file.
If he want 5 books, the code should run copy 5 books from the book shelf file and copy it in the user file and so own.

Comment: What do you think this line does ?  `if (--count == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (--count == 0)
```

is the culprit. Simplify your code and you won't have to worry about such silly errors.

```
while(count >= 0)
{ 
   getline(inFile, line);
   outFile << line <<endl;
   --count;
}
```

Comment: sir i tried this method but its not working properly. The code runs ask for the user to choice and copies the highest value number of line the user inputs. For example :cout<<"How many books do you want to buy?\n"; cin>>4(loop runs 4 times) and in this four times the highest number the user gives let suppose 2,1,5,3 the file copies 5 lines from 1 to 5

Comment: @zero001, the conditional needs to be `count >= 0`. Updatd the answer just now.